# Как обойти массив объектов и объеденить совпадающие ключи

Tags: javascript, рекурсия, lodash

Как привести такой массив:

```
 const arr = [
    {
      type: "t",
      position: {
        lg: { x: 0 },
        md: { x: 1 },
      },
    },
    {
      type: "w",
      position: {
        md: { x: 2 },
      },
    },
    {
      type: "t",
      position: {
        lg: { x: 3 },
      },
    },
  ];
```

К объекту вида:

```
{
  lg: [
    { x: 0 },
    { x: 3 }
  ],
   md: [
    { x: 1 },
    { x: 2 }
  ]
}
```

Подойдtn любой вариант: lodash, рекурсия

Comment: Какой вариант сделали вы и почему он у вас не заработал?

Comment: Для приведенного примера рекурсия не нужна. С чего вы взяли, что здесь стоит применять рекурсию?

Answer (score 0):

> lodash, рекурсия

Это все не обязательно. Достаточно пары циклов...

```js
const arr = [{
    type: "t",
    position: {
      lg: {
        x: 0
      },
      md: {
        x: 1
      },
    },
  },
  {
    type: "w",
    position: {
      md: {
        x: 2
      },
    },
  },
  {
    type: "t",
    position: {
      lg: {
        x: 3
      },
    },
  },
];

const obj = arr.reduce((o, v) => {
  ['lg', 'md'].forEach(k => v.position[k] && o[k].push(v.position[k]))
  return o
}, {
  lg: [],
  md: []
})

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Кажется узкое место, что нужно знать имена ключей объектов. Их может быть  много и они могут быть любыми. Могут совпадать, а могут повторяться n раз

Comment: @Guliver, почем мне знать? Ты ведь сам про те ключи написал в вопросе... Если сомневаешься в примере - тестируй на других данных и сличай.